# React app deployed on gh-pages, but page returns 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

[Update] As many have suspected, this error is due to yesterday's (18.10.21) github incident, it has now been fixed and so my page reappeared again. Thanks everyone

I've recently published my first React App on to gh-pages. All the files are showing in the repo, I also experienced no problem on localhost, plus terminal also gave me no problem when it is deployed.

I believe that I have the right settings in Package.json, Please see below. Can someone please help me with this issue?

and here's the repository just in case 
https://github.com/cyg65/profile

```
{
"name": "portfolio",
"version": "0.1.2",
"private": true,
"homepage": "https://cyg65.github.io/profile",
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"popper.js": "^1.14.4",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2",
"react-icons": "^3.2.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "2.0.5"
},
"scripts": {
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not ie <= 11",
"not op_mini all"
],
"devDependencies": {
"eslint-config-prettier": "^3.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
"flow-bin": "^0.83.0",
"prettier": "^1.14.3"
}
}
```

Comment: What URL are you trying  to open?

Comment: Check browser cache? Push another commit to trigger a rebuild?

Comment: your repo name should be `cyg65.github.io`

Comment: Github is also having some [issues](https://status.github.com/messages) right now. Edit: your website seems to be up and running now. https://cyg65.github.io/profile/ It is important to note that it will take some time for github page changes to reflect.

Comment: As far as I know, GitHub pages only looks for an `index.html` in the root of your repo. It seems like you can't get it to serve from the `public` folder. I found a discussion here which may be helpful: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Pages/How-to-deploy-the-public-folder/td-p/4514

Comment: I usually open from the URL provided in the settings which is  https://cyg65.github.io/profile/  and yes I have actually committed many times after. @RobinZigmond sorry the repo URL i posted is misleading, that was the master branch you were looking at, on the gh-pages branch which I deployed to, the html.index is not in a subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you @iamdevlinph for informing me of the github issue, or maybe it's a Japan thing, I still am not able to see my page, and it has been hours.

Comment: @cyg65 that's odd. I can definitely see your site. There's make-up kit brush thing. Try opening your site on incognito mode or try clearing your cache. Github has been operational today, I hope you can see your page soon.

Comment: @iamdevilinph thank you for the help, I was able to view the page as soon as github's been up and running. It is definitely caused by the breakdown.

Comment: If you did everything correctly according to [create-react-app/deploy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages) try Hard Reload and Empty Cache.